# Why I am not getting the data from API? Not sure where is the prooblem in the server or the javascript file

Tags: javascript, api

I am doing wether app API. I am using my API key via a server, which is working fine until I enter anything in the search box and receive my error message then server is crashing. So I am not able to extract the data from api. Anytime I am entering a valid city is the server is catching with my error message instead of getting my data. Is it possible there are issue with my server that does not allowed me extract data from api openWeather.org or the issue is with the code from the js file.

This is server file:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    require("dotenv").config()
}

const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY  // the api key is stoored in ".env" file
const axios = require("axios")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static("public"))

app.post("/data", (req, res) => {
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${req.body.name}&exclude=hourly,minutely&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`

    axios({
        url: url,
        responseType: "json",
    }).then(data => res.json(data.data.currently))
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server Started")
})
```

script file

```
let searchInput = document.querySelector(".search-bar");
let timeDiv = document.querySelector(".current-time");
let city = document.querySelector(".location");
let detailSection = document.querySelector(".detail-section");
let condition = document.querySelector(".status");
let tempItem = document.querySelector(".degree-section");
let currentTemp = document.querySelector(".temp");
let mgs = document.querySelector(".msg");

setInterval(() => {
    const time = new Date();
    const hour = time.getHours();
    const min = time.getMinutes();
    const ampm = hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";

    if(min < 10) {
        timeDiv.innerHTML = `<div class="time">${hour}:0${min} <span class="am-pm">${ampm}</span></div>`;
    }
    else{
        timeDiv.innerHTML = `<div class="time">${hour}:${min} <span class="am-pm">${ampm}</span></div>`;
    }
    
}, 1000);

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let cityValue = searchInput.value;
        fetch("/data", {
            method: 'POST',
            timeout: 0,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({city: cityValue})
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => { 
               this.displayWeather(data)
             })
             . catch(() => {
                mgs.textContent = `Please enter a valid city! `;
            });  
        
}); 

function displayWeather(data) {
    const { name } = data;
    const { country } = data.sys;
    const { icon, description } = data.weather[0];
    const { temp, humidity } = data.main;
    const { speed } = data.wind;
                    
    location.textContent = `Weather in ${name},${country}`;
    condition.innerHTML = `<img class="icon" scr="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}.png" /> 
                          <div class="condition">${description}</div> `;
    detailSection.innerHTML = `<div class="detail">
                                    <div class="title">Humidity</div>          
                                    <div class="humidity">${humidity}%</div>     
                                </div>
                                <div class="detail">
                                    <div class="title">Temperature</div> 
                                    <div class="degree-section">
                                        <div class="temp">${temp} °C</div> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="detail">
                                    <div class="title">Wind</div>           
                                    <div class="wind-speed">${speed} km/h</div>
                                </div>`;

                                
    tempItem.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(currentTemp.value === undefined) return;

        if(data.main.temp.unit === "celsius"){
            let fahrenheit = celsiusToFahrenheit(data.main.temp.value);
            fahrenheit = Math.floor(fahrenheit);
            tempItem.innerHTML = `<div class="temp">${fahrenheit} °F</div>`;
            data.main.temp.unit = "fahrenheit";
        }
        else {
            tempItem.innerHTML = `<div class="temp">${temp} °C</div>`;
            data.main.temp.unit === "celsius"
        }
    })
}

function celsiusToFahrenheit(temp) {
    return (temp * 9/5) + 32;
}
```

I changed the code from object with function elements to separate functions but still I am not able to extract the weather data with any valid city I am not sure where is the issue with the server which is working fine until i get my error message or in the fetch function. Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: `receive my error message` in client or server? what is the error message?

Comment: @Jaromanda The function that it is used for getting the data from api is fetch(…).then(…).then(…).catch(…). So I have implemented the catch function to show the user error if they enter invalid city name. I am always receiving the message from the catch function. I don’t know why when I enter a valid city name I get that message instead of weather data.

Comment: `the message` what message?

Comment: @Jaromanda Here is the message  `Please enter a valid city! ` which you can see in my catch function if you  check my code above.

Comment: I would `catch((err) => { console.error(err)` to see what the **actual** error is - your "Please enter a valid city" doesn't show anything about what the error may actually be

Comment: I just noticed ... you send the request with `{city: cityValue}` ... and your server uses `req.body.name` .... can you see what's wrong? also, the response from openweathermaps does NOT contain a `data` property so `data.data` is undefined and `data.data.currently` would throw an error - surprised you didn't mention the error on your server code

Comment: ignore what I said about `data.data` ... I realise that's an axios thing where the `data` is a property of the response object which you've called `data` ... so, `data.data` is the actual response data, and you're trying to read `currently` ... which doesn't exist anyway, not in that API. The one call API has a `current` property, but you aren't using that API

Comment: @JaromandaX  I wasn't sure if the server was having any issues. That is why I did not mention them. Now that I fixed my response in the server "then(data => res.json(data.data.current))" and put in js file "body: JSON.stringify({name: cityInput})" as well as using catch((err) => { console.error(err) in the Browser console I am getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at script.js:39:38". I don't have any idea what is the issue with my JSON input.

Comment: @Jaromanda Also, I am not sure what those numbers in this "script.js:39:38" what are they stand for. The words "script.js" is my file name, but what stands for those numbers after that?